# C - Program crashes or doesn't react when mutex is being used

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have to write a fileserver that allows concurrent operations using a custom protocol.

the preconditions are:

no global locks
the physical filesystem must not be touched
forks/shm or pthreads must be used.

I though about the following concept:

I'm using prthreads. A new thread is created with every client that connects.

I created a struct to simulate the files:

```
struct _sFile {
    char *filename;
    size_t size;
    char *content;
    char *location;
    sFile *next;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
};
```

a linked list of sFile is being used as the filesystem. No directories need to be taken into account

For every operation on files, two locks shall be set; one on the current file and on on the next file. whenever I iterate through the files the locks move together.

I wrote a few functions to iterate through the list:

```
void iterator_init(iterator *it){
    pthread_mutex_init(it->a->mutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(it->b->mutex,NULL);
    it->a=NULL;
    it->b=file_list;
    pthread_mutex_lock(it->b->mutex);
}

/*
 * Return the next file in the list or null if at the end.
 * If the end is reached, the iterator is already destoryed.
 */
sFile *iterator_next(iterator *it){
    if (it->a != NULL)
        pthread_mutex_unlock(it->a->mutex);
    if (it->b->next==NULL)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(it->b->mutex);
        return NULL;
    }

    it->a=it->b;
    it->b=it->b->next;
    pthread_mutex_lock(it->b->mutex);
    return it->b;
}

void iterator_destroy(iterator *it){
    if (it->a != NULL)
            pthread_mutex_unlock(it->a->mutex);
    if (it->b != NULL)
            pthread_mutex_unlock(it->b->mutex);
}
```

I tried to put a lock on the file when my client fires the command LIST. This is my list command:

```
void cmd_list(int ac, char *av) {
    iterator it;
    iterator_init(&it);
    sFile *list = file_list;
    long num_files = file_count;
    char ack[32];
    sprintf(ack, "ACK %d\n", file_count);
    send(client_sock, ack, (int) strlen(ack), 0);
    sFile *current = list;
    while ((current=iterator_next(&it))!=NULL){
    send(client_sock, current->filename, strlen(current->filename), 0);
}
```

}

But the application crashes on

```
interator_init(&it)
```

in the cmd_create function.

What am I doing wrong? Sometimes, the lock works but the client is waiting endlessly and the comand is being sent to the server unless the client stops.

The source code of the entire application is on

https://github.com/fish-guts/concurrent

Any hints would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: did you initialize the mutex ?

Comment: Yes I have initialized the mutex in the processing function. 

The source code for this is project is under

https://github.com/fish-guts/concurrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the mutex with [`pthread_mutex_init()`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_mutex_init.txt) before you can use it. `iterator_init()` tries to lock the mutex in the struct it gets as a parameter without initializing it.

Comment: Yes I have initialized the mutex in the processing function. The source code for this is project is under http://github.com/fish-guts/concurrent

Comment: Every thread that gets created will call the function doprocessing() and the mutex is initialized there.

Comment: @Fish-Guts: The mutex in the `it` iterator in `cmd_list()` doesn't get initialized. `it` just gets passed to `iterator_init()`, which tries to lock the uninitialized mutex.

Comment: Does this mean I need to initialize every mutex with every call?

Comment: @Fish-Guts: Every time you create a mutex you have to initialize it. Since `iterator_init()` seems to be the function responsible for initializing new iterators, that would be the appropriate function to initialize the mutex contained in the iterator (before it tries to lock it). Additionally there should also be a function to destroys no longer needed iterators, which then would destroy the mutex with `pthread_mutex_destroy()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have a function called iterator_destroy, i will call pthread_mutex_destroy then. I'll test that and give feedback. 
Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have now changed the way I initialize mutex, but something seems to wrong... my program crashes when I try to initialize the mutex:

    void iterator_init(iterator *it){

     pthread_mutex_init(it->a->mutex,NULL);

     pthread_mutex_init(it->b->mutex,NULL);
     it->a=NULL;
     it->b=file_list;
     pthread_mutex_lock(it->b->mutex);
     }